# parse Json response with attributes

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to parse Json result below fromAjax response. Foreach CostingItem i need to access to UnitPrice.Amount, but I got error.

Can someone help me to access items?

I got this response from Laravel based webservice.

```
{
    "CostingItem": [{
        "@attributes": {
            "Description": "Basic Price",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "PassengerRPH": "1",
            "PriceBasis": "Passenger"
        },
        "UnitPrice": {
            "@attributes": {
                "Amount": "1823.82",
                "OriginalAmount": "1974.32"
            }
        },
        "ExtendedPrice": {
            "@attributes": {
                "Amount": "1823.82",
                "OriginalAmount": "1974.32"
            }
        },
        "Commission": {
            "@attributes": {
                "Rate": "11.00",
                "Type": "P"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "@attributes": {
            "Description": "Basic Price",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "PassengerRPH": "2",
            "PriceBasis": "Passenger"
        },
        "UnitPrice": {
            "@attributes": {
                "Amount": "1823.82",
                "OriginalAmount": "1974.32"
            }
        },
        "ExtendedPrice": {
            "@attributes": {
                "Amount": "1823.82",
                "OriginalAmount": "1974.32"
            }
        },
        "Commission": {
            "@attributes": {
                "Rate": "11.00",
                "Type": "P"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

> here is the script used in Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/public/fetch-bambini",
    data: {
        id: d,
        tipologia: tipologia,
        bambini: bambini,
        neonati: neonati,
        adulti: adulti
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $.each(response.CostingItem, function(k, v) {
            console.log(v);
        });
    }
});
```

This return this response:

[image]

Comment: Please show the script that you are getting an error with. *However*, you do have a trailing `,` at the end that is invalid

Comment: Looks like you are missing `dataType: 'json'` from your AJAX request parameters.